# URLEncode not working on a picklist field in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a custom button using Javascript on Opportunity. On the opportunity object we already have relationship field which relates back to Opportunity (like Parent-Child).

The javascript button will copy the values of certain field from the Parent opportunity and auto populate in the new child opportunity created. All the values are copied to child opportunity, but except for picklist values which has "&" in the value.. When i use urlencode like below, it is throwing the below error:

00NK0000001jyxH={!URLENCODE(Opportunity.ABC__c)}

Error: Field Opportunity.HBS_ePSF_Branch_Location__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEXT function is used to return value of a Picklist in custom button or in formula field

update your code in following manner

```
00NK0000001jyxH={!URLENCODE(TEXT(Opportunity.ABC__c))}
```